# What's the best plugin for allowing javascript in a post or page?

Tags: plugins, javascript

Just looking for a recommendation on the best plugin to allow javascript in a post or page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, you could just give users the 'unfiltered_html' capability. This can be done with a plugin such as [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/).

**Warning:** don't allow untrusted users to insert random scripts into the post content. With JavaScript, they can steal HTTP cookies from other users, including yourself, giving them administrator rights, basically.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I will test your suggestion, as well as the previous from another user.